# How to create POJO if I don't have a json?

Tags: android, json

I want to parse website using retrofit, but I don't know how to create POJO.
And I don't have a json.

```
http://vuzopedia.ru/vuz/
```

This is the website where I want to parse information.

Comment: Is this website secure to check it out?

Comment: Posibly duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280410/get-html-of-a-website-with-retrofit-android

Comment: what does this have to do with android?

Answer (score 1):

if your website does not have an API or anyway to get JSON data then you should consider Web Scraping. You cant make POJO/Models without JSON Data